# NoSuchMethodError: The method '[ ]' was called on null | Parsing a JSON

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am extracting data from a JSON but I get this error.

```
    > I/flutter ( 4999): NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.     
    > I/flutter ( 4999): Receiver: null
    > I/flutter ( 4999): Tried calling: []("thumbnail")
```

The code snippet for above error -

```
factory ImageLinks.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    final finger = parsedJson["thumbnail"];
    print(finger);
    return ImageLinks(
      thumb: finger,
    );
  }
```

Output for print(parsedJson) -

```
{smallThumbnail: http://books.google.com/books/content?id=miiADwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&edge=curl&source=gbs_api, 
thumbnail: http://books.google.com/books/content?id=miiADwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api}
```

Please Help!

Comment: parsedJson is null

Comment: Does this answer your question? [flutter - The method '\[\]' was called on null (parse json)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53009529/flutter-the-method-was-called-on-null-parse-json)

Comment: @PetrusNguyễnTháiHọc but i printed parsedJson and it has data see above

Comment: @Ashmit You need to share other relevant part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you've using `http` package. Have you decode your response data?

```
Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson = jsonDecode(jsonString);
```

Comment: Yes, I have already decoded the response. Also when i print parsedJson, it prints the data instead of null.

Comment: Let's put print(parsedJson) inside the function, this process should be right